# How to convert AVIF To PNG with Python?

Tags: python, image

I have an image file in avif format
How can I convert this file to png format?

I found some code to convert jpg files to avif, but I didn't find any code to reconvert them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to install this modules: **pip install pillow-avif-plugin Pillow**

Then:

```
from PIL import Image
import pillow_avif

img = Image.open('input.avif')
img.save('output.png')
```